# How to perform Excel Relative reference formula in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
=IF(AND(C2=C1,A2=A1,F2=F1,K2=K1,LEFT(B2,8)<>LEFT(B1,8)),"same","")
```

How to perform above excel formula in python? Need to create a loop to perform the formula for the whole column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
# cond1 & cond2 Is equivalent to `AND`
# use shift(1) to compare the row and it's previous row
# str[:8] Is equivalent to `LEFT(B2,8)`
#  np.where Is equivalent to `IF`

cond = True
for col in ['C', 'A', 'F', 'K']:
    cond &= df[col] == df[col].shift(1)
cond &= df['B'].str[:8] == df['B'].str[:8].shift(1)

np.where(cond, "same", "")
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, make it as the answer (checkmark on left side of post). Posters get reputation points for their selected answers.